# Kubuntu - External Monitor not detected

Tags: kubuntu, 14.10, vga

I have a second Monitor now and it's plugged into the VGA Port of my Thinkpad W530. But the monitor is not detected. I have 2 Graphic Units, so it should be able to work with 2 Monitors.
I use Kubuntu 14.10. Does anyone have any idea what I have to do to get Kubuntu working with that Monitor (Its an pretty old Fujitsu Siemens)?

I use the NVIDIA Binary Driver Version 331.133 from the Driver Manager. I tried already with the normal X.org Driver.

I don't want to have to use Windows, just for being able to use a second monitor.

lshw shows for -display:

```
*-display
                description: VGA compatible controller
                product: GK107GLM [Quadro K2000M]
                vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
                version: a1
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
                configuration: driver=nvidia latency=0
                resources: irq:50 memory:f0000000-f0ffffff memory:c0000000-cfffffff memory:d0000000-d1ffffff ioport:5000(size=128) memory:f1000000-f107ffff
        *-display
             description: VGA compatible controller
             product: 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
             version: 09
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
             configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
             resources: irq:46 memory:f1400000-f17fffff memory:e0000000-efffffff ioport:6000(size=64)
```

Thanks in advance, I am grateful for any kind of help to get this monitor working in linux.

Comment: I use the NVIDIA Binary Driver 331 from the Driver Manager. But even while using the X.org it doesn't work. I also updated the question with the information.

Comment: Nothing happens.

Comment: So much for downloading the user manual for your TP 530...  (comments deleted as they're in your question anyway: you should do the same thing).  How technical are you?  Do yo know what a PPA is?  Do you know about rolling application versions forward and rolling backward?

Comment: Yeah I know what a PPA is. And I am able to add PPAs and install applications and update it via terminal. About rolling backwards I am not sure what you mean. But the user manual from the Thinkpad doesn't help, since they are only supporting Windows and there it works out of the box. I searched for an answer like 5h and after nothing worked out I asked a question.

Comment: Answer coming up...

Answer (score 1):

The standard Ubuntu NVidia drivers generate some problems on slightly older *and* slightly newer NVidia hardware.

If you want *more* then the standard Ubuntu repository drivers, install the [xorg.edgers](https://launchpad.net/~xorg-edgers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) PPA.  As the xorg.edgers group ask not to give installation instructions directly without linking to their page, this is the best I can do.

This PPA will allow you to install *experimental drivers* which you then will be able to install.  I would start with the 346 as it runs 10°C cooler then the other ones at the time of this writing.